# BOOST - Class template queue

Tags: c++, boost

I was trying to read on [Boost Class template queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) and found the below content of class template:

```
template<typename T, typename A0, typename A1, typename A2> 
class queue {
    public:
  // member classes/structs/unions
  template<typename T, typename... Options> 
  struct implementation_defined {
    // types
    typedef node_allocator allocator;
    typedef std::size_t    size_type;
  };
  // construct/copy/destruct
  queue(void);
  template<typename U> 
    explicit queue(typename node_allocator::template rebind< U >::other const &);
  explicit queue(allocator const &);
  explicit queue(size_type);
  template<typename U> 
    queue(size_type, 
          typename node_allocator::template rebind< U >::other const &);
  ~queue(void);
.......
};
```

I was trying to understand the template step by step - so

```
template<typename T, typename A0, typename A1, typename A2>
```

meant to me that the template would be created when provided types T, A0, A1 and A2 like

```
queue<int, char, myclass, char>
```

where myclass is a user defined class - I hope I am correct in my understanding. But what I could not understand is the below section -

```
  template<typename T, typename... Options> 
  struct implementation_defined {
    // types
    typedef node_allocator allocator;
    typedef std::size_t    size_type;
  };
  // construct/copy/destruct
  queue(void);
  template<typename U> 
    explicit queue(typename node_allocator::template rebind< U >::other const &);
```

It seems a template inside another template - but then how do we provide types to instantiate

```
template<typename T, typename... Options>
```

and

```
template<typename U>
```

Is there a way to understand template construction like classes to understand what a templates methods are its arguments and return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template<typename U>` is a `queue` constructor function template. Its parameter is deduced from argument you are passing when invoking it.

`struct implementation_defined` is a regular nested class, that is not actually a template itself. It looks like a documentation issue because it is actually [defined as](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp)

```
struct implementation_defined
{
    typedef node_allocator allocator;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
};
```